# How to back-trace in CSS trying to change div color when checkbox inside div is checked?

Tags: html, css

I have one `div` which have one checkbox, I am trying to change color of `div` when checkbox checked - unchecked using `HTML` `CSS` only without using `JavaScript`. But as `CSS` doesn't support backtrace I am not sure how to achieve this.

CSS:

```css
.content {
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="content">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use javascript? Depending on your structure and desired result, you could put the style in the checkbox in a way that "overflow" and take the div space...not really a good practice though.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro There is no as such big reason, but we are creating on library which has some limitations (for various business reasons) in which we are trying to achieve most of the thing using pure CSS

Comment: I see...as far as I know, it is not possible to change the style of a parent component based in the child component. So you either use JS or some kind of "overflow" solution :(

Comment: If you use JS you can add a data-attribute to the div that is true/false matching the checkbox value. Then use css to style using that attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 4):

I have wrapped the `checkbox` and the `span` inside a `label` and then added the CSS below:

```css
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}

input:checked+span {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<label for="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="content">
   
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Since the label wrapps around the checkbox, it doesn't need the `for` attribute.

Comment: `label` is not allowed to contain `div`. This should be made into a `span` or something else from the [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) allowed inside of a label.

Comment: @misorude I have updated my ans. and thanks for the info